# how to get origin value after a tree node was changed by editing

Tags: java, swing

I hava a editable JTree,and I add TreeModelListener for it.I want to know how to record(get) origin value for every node after I edit it.

Comment: Keep a cache of the values

Comment: The value is a String.Could you give me more details?

Comment: @lution use the [pattern Memento](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Thank you very much.

Comment: So, [`TreeCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellEditor.html) will call [`TreeModel#valueForPathChanged`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged-javax.swing.tree.TreePath-java.lang.Object-) at this point you have the opportunity to get the old value of the node before the new value is applied, at this point, you can record what ever actions you want at this point

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks very much.I will try both this way and memento pattern.

Comment: Yes,I achieve this in your way!

Answer (score 1):

So,after helped by @MadProgrammer and @Sergiy Medvynskyy, I achieved this.
I @Override valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) in DefaultTreeModel, using path to find out the edited node,then getUserObject of it which is the oldValue.The key point is write your own code before super.valueForPathChanged(path, newValue); So that you can get oldValue.
Sample:

```
typelTreeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(typeTreeRoot){
                @Override
                public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode editNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
                    int level = editNode.getLevel();
                    if(level == 2){
                        String oldValue = (String) editNode.getUserObject();
                        System.out.println(oldValue);
                    }
                    super.valueForPathChanged(path, newValue);
                }
            };
```